For P.E.C boundary conditions in a 3D cavity. Will the electric fields in all the directions be zero?
I am trying to simulate the steady state field pattern in a 3D cavity using the Finite Difference Frequency Domain method. The conditions of the simulation are given below.

A 3D cavity with the PEC boundary is considered.
An elementary dipole source generates EM fields at a specific known frequency inside the cavity.
A cubical scatterer with non-zero conductivity is present in the centre of the cavity. The scatterer is linear, homogeneous, and isotropic.
The relative permeability is 1. Permittivity is some value greater than 1.
There are no other sources/charges.

I am aware that tangential fields along any PEC surface is zero.
With no surface charges, will the normal components of the fields in the PEC boundary be zero? In other words, for the simulation, can I set all the field components (Ex, Ey and Ez) along the PEC boundary(in all the faces of the cavity) to zero?
Please clarify.

Whether somewhere the normal component $E_n$ to the PEC boundary is zero or not depends on the cavity's shape; but in general it can have any value. Specifically, there must be somewhere on a PEC wall $E_n \ne 0$ representing an oscillating charge accumulation otherwise there cannot be a field inside.

Will the normal fields on the PEC surface be non zero, even if the cavity is a cube/cuboid?

check out the fundamental mode  $TE_{101}$ of a rectangular cavity of dimensions $a_x,a_y,a_z$: $E_y=\propto \sin\frac{\pi x}{a_x}\sin \frac{\pi z}{a_z}$ and $E_x=E_z=0$. This can be viewed as a standing wave of the waveguide mode $TE_{10}$ between two metal walls along $z$ at a distance $a_z$ apart.
